# Can't create a marker for a Leaflet map, it throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When trying to create a marker, I see an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function at e.addTo
>   (leaflet.js:5)

The map itself is showing up normally.

Everything is as in the documentation: [map usage](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-example), [tileLayer usage](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tilelayer), [marker usage](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#marker).

Leaflet script and CSS (from a CDN) are added to HTML file, as shown here: [download Leaflet page](http://leafletjs.com/download.html).

Here's my code:

```js
const map = L.map('map', {
  center: [55.751244, 37.618423],
  zoom: 13,
});

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaW5zYXRpYWJsZS1taW5kIiwiYSI6ImNqOWIwaWdrNjFjdDIzM24ya21qbGJuMzQifQ.EIK16areNxtGW7AyBTug6A',
}).addTo(map);

map.locate({
  setView: true,
});


L.marker([55.751244, 37.618423]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: To me its all working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ubLy9q82/

Comment: You're right, thank you! The problem occurs when I add marker in another module, where the map module is imported to. Do you have any suggestions what can cause this problem?